Failed to construct 'ResizeObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Function'
I am trying to render HTML inside textarea and I have an ajax call from the controller to read the value and parse it as  var to the render() function.
I followed the question here
However, the render() function failed when I tried to use ResizeObserver within the ajax call. If I specifically define var explain = "<b style =\"color:blue;\">Risky</b>";, the content can be rendered in onload but not within the ajax call.
May I know what am I missing here?
These are my codes:
@Html.TextArea("", new { @id = "box", @oninput = "render()"})
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

      var job_ID = "1";
      var explain = "";

        onload = function () {
                LoadJobResult(job_ID);         
        }

function render() {

            var inp = document.getElementById("box");
            inp.innerHTML += explain;

            var data =
                `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="${inp.offsetWidth}" height="${inp.offsetHeight}">
                <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">
                <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-size:13.3px;padding:2px;">
                ${inp.value} <i style="color:red">Model Explanation</i>
                </div>
                </foreignObject>
                </svg>`;

            var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/svg+xml' });
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            inp.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + URL.createObjectURL(blob) + ")";
        }


function LoadJobResult(ID) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/controller/Get_JobResult',
                type: 'Get',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { 'job_ID': ID },
                success: function (result) {
                    var res = JSON.parse(result);

                    $("#box").val(res[0]['DRP_Explanation_Txt']);
                    explain = res[0]['DRP_Explanation_Txt']; 
                    
                    render();
                    ro = new ResizeObserver(render(explain));
                    ro.observe(document.getElementById("box"));
                },
                error: function (emp, err) {
                    console.log('my message' + err);
                }
            });         
        }
  });


</script>



notice, how the question you apparently followed does new ResizeObserver(render); and you don't

@JaromandaX I have edited the question to match the OP

new ResizeObserver(render()); is different to new ResizeObserver(render); - there's a subtle difference between an argument being a function and the result of calling a function

I suggest you could modify your codes to pass the render function instead render(explain) then it will work well.
render() function and render(explain) function is different things.
More details, you could refer to below example:
function LoadJobResult(ID) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/controller/Get_JobResult',
                type: 'Get',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: { 'job_ID': ID },
                success: function (result) {
                    var res = JSON.parse(result);

                    $("#box").val(res[0]['DRP_Explanation_Txt']);
                    explain = res[0]['DRP_Explanation_Txt']; 
                    
                    render();
                    var ro = new ResizeObserver(() => render());
                    ro.observe(document.getElementById("box"));
                },
                error: function (emp, err) {
                    console.log('my message' + err);
                }
            });         
        }
  });

Result:

